# Headless docker host with a headful container

Tags: docker, virtualization, coreos, rancher

TL; DR: Can I configure a container to access natively the VGA, overriding the host video output?

---

I'm thinking about disposing of my low-power XenServer (previously ESXi) whitebox to setup a docker minimal installation (e.g. CoreOS, RancherOs or a similar distribution). Would it be possible to give a (possibly not privileged) container exclusive access/passthrough to the video output, to install a media center solution (e.g. Kodi) that could run together with all the other containers, with a fullscreen video output to a TV, "obviously" with hardware accelerated video decoding?

I'm trying to move between `--privileged`, `--device`, `-v /dev/vga?:....` but I have to admin I'm quite new to this and the only informations I could find were related to [USB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34302096/sharing-devices-webcam-usb-drives-etc-with-docker) or [CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185405/using-gpu-from-a-docker-container): similar, but not exactly the same thing.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

With a little bit of pain you will be able to configure minimal install of xserver and video drivers on host, and after that with a little bit of pain configure container to use passed x11 socket from host machine.

Comment: Interesting suggestion, I'll try to give a look into it.